# POWERSHELL - Check if samaccountname exists if yes use different method

Tags: function, powershell

)

Im a new Programmer and i am in an Internship right now. I was asked to write a Script, where they create an entry in AD. So far it was pretty straight forward, to create the function to just create the user:

```
function getSamAccountName([string]$givennname, [string]$surname)
        {
            return ($givennname.Substring(0, 2) + $surname.Substring(0, 2)).ToLower()

        }
```

Now they want to add that if this ADUser allready exist (due to simular names),that this script should use following patterns:

Version 1 : First 4 Letters (Lastname)

Version 2 : First 2 Letters (Lastname) First 2 Letters (Surname)

Version 3 : First 2 Letters (Lastname) Last 2 Letters (Surname)

Version 4 In case the Lastname only has 3 Letters : First 3 Letters (Lastname) and first of the Surname

Everything i could find on google, was from CSV-Files or something i just cant understand;D

Here is the missing Part, sorry;D

```
function getSamAccountName([string]$givennname, [string]$surname)
        {
            $SANarray = @(

                        $SANv1 = ($givennname.Substring(0, 4))
                        $SANv2 = ($surname.Substring(0, 2) + $givenname.Substring(0, 2)).ToLower()
                        $SANv3 = ($givennname.Substring(0, 2) + $surname.Substring(0, -2)).ToLower()
                        $SANv4 = ($givennname.Substring(0, 3) + $surname.Substring(0, 1)).ToLower()
            )


            foreach ($san in $SANarray)
            {
                if (get-aduser -Identity $SAN -eq $SANv1) { Write-Verbose "SANv1 already Taken" }
                else { return $SANv1 }
                if (get-aduser -Identity $SAN -eq $SANv2) { Write-Verbose "SANv2 already Taken" }
                else { return $SANv2 }
                if (get-aduser -Identity $SAN -eq $SANv3) { Write-Verbose "SANv3 already Taken" }
                else { return $SANv3 }
                if (get-aduser -Identity $SAN -eq $SANv4) { Write-Verbose "SANv4 already Taken" }
                else { return $SANv4 }
            }
```

This is the Error i receive :

```
    ERROR: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
AutomatedTicked.ps1 (116, 7): ERROR: At Line: 116 char: 7
ERROR: + ...             $SANv2 = ($surname.Substring(0, 2) + $givenname.Substring ...
ERROR: +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
ERROR:
ERROR: ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
```

I hope some nice Folks can help me;))

(feel free to ask any questions because i dont know if those informations are enough;)

Comment: have you tried searching for this? this is a _very common task_ ... and there are great gobs of examples on the web ... [*grin*]

Comment: also, can you talk them into using something less _freakishly insane_ for the user name scheme? [*grin*] the sensible way is to use the allowed number of letters plus a sequence number. do it for ALL users, even the 1st `JDoe` would be `JDoe01`.

Comment: "Everything i could find on google, was from CSV-Files or something i just cant understand;D"

Comment: trust me i tried;D they wanna stick to it;( i cant seem to find what you want me to search for?

Comment: The description of your task is clear, but I can't find a single _question_ in your post! Are you expecting us to explain every single line of code that google surfaces? :)

Comment: I added the missing statement, did  not know why it went away, same with "Hey Folks;)" at the beginning;)